# Remove the border inside color input

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/WpJRk/

I have a color picker in my page using the new "color" type input:

```
<input type="color">
```

However, there is a black "border" inside the element which seems not able to be removed.

[image]

> There is a 1px black box inside the field.

I don't really want the box inside. Doing this:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

doesn't help.

Any solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following CSS ruleset:

```
input::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thought it was the outline... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your jsFiddle doesn't show a box. (At least for me)[image: **Screen Capture**]

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the question that the only browser I wish to support is Chrome. If you view it in Firefox it might not work. By the way, one question: how did you take such a high definition screenshot?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I actually took this screenshot from Chrome on my iPad. (That's why the screenshot is HD!) That could be why it's not shown exactly the way yours is.

Comment: Chrome on the iPad (and iOS) is a UIWebView (so it should have the same rendering characteristics as mobile Safari) Apple has been very restrictive of approving any app that replaces part of the Apple standard SDK

Comment: @JasonSperske Yeah they are both built on webkit.

Comment: @David I see. I believe you will have to open up the demo on a desktop since the native color picker is not supported by Chrome for iOS.

Comment: To a degree you are correct however any attempt to treat them as having any identical behavior is likely to leave you shaking your fist in Cupertino or Mountain View's direction: http://www.paulirish.com/2013/webkit-for-developers/

Answer (score 1):

How about the following plugin instead?

http://jscolor.com/

Comment: I don't really want another library included in my page just because of the color picker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you're attempting to do.

`<input type="color">` is intended to show a color picker so for the element to denote that's what it does it defaults to black for the color. You can change the color value like you've done to match the background color (`input type="color">` can't have an empty value), but you'll still have to contend with the border piece.