# Remove inside border in type=color

Tags: html, css, firefox

When I use type=color as an input, it has two borders. Setting border=none will only remove the outer border. However, there is one tiny one inside. I tried many other properties and still the same result. Here is my code:

```css
input[type="color"] {
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    padding:0;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="name1" id="name1" value="#ffffff">
```

Here is what I mean: https://ibb.co/N3nVFqn
I basically want to remove that border.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the border inside color input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865121/remove-the-border-inside-color-input)

Comment: It does for chrome but not for Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `::-webkit-color-swatch` selector.

```css
input[type="color"] {
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    padding:0;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
::-webkit-color-swatch{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="name1" id="name1" value="#ffffff">
```

For Mozilla Firefox, use `::-moz-color-swatch`:

```css
input[type="color"] {
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    padding:0;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
::-moz-color-swatch{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" name="name1" id="name1" value="#ffffff">
```

Comment: This works for chrome but not for Firefox. Is there an option for Firefox too?

Comment: @mdja123cs Updated

Comment: Upvoted as useful .. OP Please add "Firefox" to your original question --

Answer (score 2):

if you change the two borders to none you can eliminate both of them

```css
input[type="color"] {
    appearance: none;
    border:solid 1px red;
    padding:0;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:white;
    box-sizing:unset;
}



input[type="color" i]::-webkit-color-swatch {
border:solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="color" name="name1" id="name1" value="#ffffff">
</div>
```